# Dataloader from the Command Line: Change Query Request Size in XML Bean

Tags: data-loader

Is it possible to change the Query Request Size when running Data Loader from the command line. I tried adding "sfdc.queryrequestsize" to the XML bean with no luck.

[image]

Example of my attempt to change the Query Request Size from the XML bean.

```
<entry key="sfdc.timeoutSecs" value="600"/>
<entry key="sfdc.loadBatchSize" value="200"/>
<entry key="sfdc.queryrequestsize" value="2000"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use **extractionRequestSize**, for example:

`<entry key="sfdc.extractionRequestSize" value="2000"/>`

Documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=loader_params.htm).